# R : Counting the number of observations per category

Tags: r, dataset, preprocessing, counts

I'm currently starting out in R and wondering how to count the number of observations per day, per node, per replicate from the below dataset, and store in a different data set.
The original dataset looks like this:
[image]

Would like the resulting dataset to look like this:
[image]

Can someone help me find out how I could do this in R?
Thanks

Comment: in the future please ask programming questions on https://stackoverflow.com/, you're more likely to get a fast answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with the `dplyr` package. The `dplyr` package has the functions `group_by` to group your data by one or more variables and `summarise` to do some aggregation function. The `dplyr` package also supports the 'pipe' notation `%>%`. This notation means the output of the previous function is the first argument of the next function. Here is what it might look like for one of your variables. The `dplyr` package is also nice in that its function do not require column names to be quoted or in character vectors.

```
library(dplyr)
my_summary_data <- mydata %>%
    group_by(Replicate) %>%
    summarise(Count = n())      
# The last line creates a new column named Count with a value calculated by n(), 
# which counts observations (rows) per group.
```

The output looks something like:

```
my_summary_data
Replicate  Count
1          8
2          7
```

The `group_by` function can group by multiple columns, so

```
my_summary_data <- mydata %>%
    group_by(Replicate, Node) %>%
    summarise(Count = n())
```

will produce:

```
Replicate  Node  Count
1          1     5
1          2     3
2          1     7
```

Answer (score 0):

I like  to use the `plyr` library but there are other ways:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(mydata, c('Replicate','Node','Day'), nrow)
```

- the `dd` in `ddply` means that the input is a **d**ataframe and the output is also a **d**ataframe
- the rows are grouped by the values of columns given as second argument
- the last argument is the function to apply on every group, in this case `nrow` to simply count the number of rows in the group.

If you want to name the column in the same time you can do:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(mydata, c('Replicate','Node','Day'), function(groupDF) {
  data.frame(countObservations=nrow(groupDF))
})
```